# Adding a phase to a circuit using standard gates

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

How do I add an arbitrary overall phase to the circuit using standard gates?

Yes, I know that the overall phase it irrelevant, yet this is only true until you control the circuit on extra qubits. Yes, in that case the overall phase of the controlled circuit [can be fixed using gates on control qubits](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16898/6313). But my question is on how to do it using standard gates (i.e., those available in qiskit) on qubits of the circuit itself.

An example: an overall $-1$ factor can be added by appending $XZXZ$ gate sequence to any qubit. Can I do smth like this be done for an arbitrary phase using rotation gates?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27066/9474

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!